# How to download a release from a private repo using wget or curl?

Tags: github

A Github `release` has been made whose repository is `private`.

Anybody can download that release (source code as `tar` files) using `wget` or `curl` command.

Should `wget` or `curl` embed personal access token(authorization) associated with the`private` repo in order to download the tar files every time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try setting up Personal access token first? You need to do that and then pass that as part of Authorization Header in curl request

Comment: @Aniket thanks for the comment. What do you mean by `setting up`? Do you mean to generate a `personal access token` at `repo` level? Suppose I have a copy of such a token. Now, the question is that someone wants to download the release from that `private` repository. Should he need the `personal access token` in order to download the tar files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a repository is set to private, then its releases are also private.

If your objective is to provide public releases while maintaining private source code, then you'll need to publish the releases using a different channel (a mechanism separate from that private repository).

One way is to maintain a separate public repository just for the release artifacts. Another way is to use GitHub's dedicated [packages](https://github.com/features/packages) feature (if it applies to your artifacts).

---

In response to the question in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130068/how-to-download-a-release-from-a-private-repo-using-wget-or-curl/74133728#comment130888886_74130068):

> Now, the question is that someone wants to download the release from that private repository. Should he need the personal access token in order to download the tar files?

Yes. See [Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) in the docs.

Comment: Unless I publish `personal access token`, nobody can download the release from a `private` repo. What is the risk involved if the `token` is published with restricted scope? Because using `git api` calls anybody,  with possession of token, can damage the `repo`.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130068/how-to-download-a-release-from-a-private-repo-using-wget-or-curl/74133728?noredirect=1#comment130893379_74133728) @Marmayogi That’s a separate question to search for or [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about.

Comment: I see your point @jsejcksn. I approve your answer.